# Discord.js error trying write a role id to a botconfig.json file and then add that role to a mentioned member

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently writing a discord bot and I am having trouble on my temp mute command. I have the command check if there is a role in the server with the name "Muted" and if not create a new role and add the role id to my botconfig.json file.

Code to check for a "Muted" in the guild:

```
let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
let mutedRole = botconfig.muted;
let muteReason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
let toMute = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);

if(!message.guild.roles.find(_role => _role.name == "Muted")) {
    message.guild.createRole({
        name: "Muted",
        color: "#ff0000" 
    }).then(_mutedRole => {
        _mutedRole.setPermissions(['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'CONNECT']);
        botconfig.muted = _mutedRole.id;
        mutedRole = _mutedRole;
        fs.writeFileSync("./botconfig.json", JSON.stringify(botconfig, null, 4));
      }).catch(_error => console.log(_error));
}
```

My code to add role to the mentioned user:

```
if(message.member.hasPermission(["ADMINISTRATOR", "MANAGE_ROLES", ])) {
    if(!toMute || !args[2] || !muteReason) {
        return message.reply(`**Please follow this usage:**\n\`${prefix}mute <@user> <length> <reason>\``);
    }
    if(toMute.roles.has(mutedRole)) { return message.reply("**This user is already muted!**")};
    let muteLength = Date.now() + timestring(args[1], "ms");
    toMute.addRole(mutedRole);
```

This throws the error:

```
(node:18632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
at GuildMember.addRole (c:\Users\Cody Schultz\Documents\Discord.js\cosmo-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildMember.js:454:38)
at Statement.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Cody Schultz\Documents\Discord.js\cosmo-bot\commands\mute.js:35:20)
(node:18632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18632) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Whats return if you try `console.log(mutedRole)`  before add role?

Most likely the role assignment event occurs later than the promise with role parameters is returned

Comment: In my botconfig.json it updates `"muted": "674858073101434901"`, `console.log(mutedRole)` returns `674858073101434901`

Comment: Hmm, try this 

message.guild.roles.get(mutedRole) and console.log this, maybe id is wrong

Comment: If i restart my bot then it will add the role, but it only throws an error if it has to create a new role beforehand

Comment: so like  i say:  ***Most likely the role assignment event occurs later than the promise with role parameters is returned***  you can use `await create role` for wait for a promisse